# Free online service to send SMS FROM different countries

Tags: internationalization, sms

Need to test how international SMS messages are handled by some service. Does anybody know any online free service allowing to send SMS internationally and choose the country which phone number is used to send SMS (i.e. origin number)?
I found a service providing ability to choose phone number in various countries to receive SMS messages, but need the opposite. 
I don't need high volume or any API, couple messages sent with web form is enough for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several such websites that allow sending text online. Here is the website I found helpful for me when sending and receiving SMS from different countries around the world.
[Send A Text](https://freephonenum.com)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't allow to select the origin country. Ex. I need to send SMS from Egypt to US phone number, but it is not possible.